# iFrame Play button doesn't respond if I change HTML content code

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

I've external html to display webcam streaming in my UIWebView.

Everything work, but I would like to erase the first part of content. But when I'm erasing this content in HTML, the iFrame button doesn't longer respond... (iOS 7). (iOS 8 is OK).

Here is my HTML code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            #Hidden{background-color:red;display:hidden;}
        </style>
    </head>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/featured/about/">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li class="first"><a href="/sitemap.xml" title="Site Map">Site Map</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.bundoransurfshop.com/index.php/catalogsearch/term/popular/" title="Search Terms">Search Terms</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.bundoransurfshop.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/" title="Advanced Search">Advanced Search</a></li>
                            <li class=" last"><a href="/contact/" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <form action="http://bundoransurfco.circulator.ie/SubscriberAdd.aspx" method="post" id="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="#" value="">
                                <div class="form-subscribe">
                                    <label for="newsletter">Newsletter Sign-up:</label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="input" title="Sign up for our newsletter" class="input-text required-entry">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="RedirectUrl" value="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/">
                                                </div>
                                    <button type="submit" title="Submit" class="button"><span><span>Submit</span></span></button>
                                </div>
                        </form>
                        <address>
                            © 2010 Bundoran Surf Co. <a href="http://www.circulator.com/">Email Marketing</a> by Circulator. <a href="http://www.jet.ie/">Web Design and Development by JET.ie</a>
                        </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="main">
                <div class="post">
                    <h1><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Web " style="width: 55px; height: 36px;"><canvas width="85" height="44" style="width: 85px; height: 44px; top: -6px; left: -3px;"></canvas><cufontext>Web </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Cam" style="width: 48px; height: 36px;"><canvas width="64" height="44" style="width: 64px; height: 44px; top: -6px; left: -3px;"></canvas><cufontext>Cam</cufontext></cufon></h1>
                    <p>
                    <iframe src="http://www.myipstream.com/iframes/bundoransurfco" style="width: 720px; height: 600px;" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
                    </iframe>
                    </p>   
                </div>
                <div class="navigation">
                    <div class="alignleft"></div>
                    <div class="alignright"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

If I erase for example

```
<ul>
                            <li><a href="/featured/about/">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

the button play on iframe doesn't longer respond ... why ?
How can I erase the content that I want, without loose responding ?

Answer (score 0):

Change code for this :

```
<html>
<div style="width: 760px; height: 500px; overflow: scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;">
    <iframe src="http://www.myipstream.com/iframes/bundoransurfco" style="width:1000px; height:10000px;">
        </iframe>
</div>
</html>
```

And it works... :)